# get rid of slashes after capture.output in R

Tags: r, paste

In R, I need to write the output of paste0 to variable and need to get rid of slashes before doublequotes.

```
paste0('interpol_df[["gene',i, '"]][["y"]]')
[1] "interpol_df[[\"gene1565\"]][[\"y\"]]"
```

With `cat` one cat get rid of `\`

```
cat(paste0('interpol_df[["gene',i, '"]][["y"]]'))
interpol_df[["gene1565"]][["y"]]
```

To write the result to a variable, one cat use `capture.output`:

```
capture.output(cat(paste0('interpol_df[["gene',i, '"]][["y"]]')))
```

But `\` is back again!

```
[1] "interpol_df[[\"gene1565\"]][[\"y\"]]"
```

`sprintf` also did not help. Any suggestion on how to get rid of it?

EDIT:

That piece of code is withing a `for` loop, which looks like:

```
inter_data<-NULL
for (i in 0:1565){
  y_col<-cat(paste('interpol_df[["gene',i, '"]][["y"]]'))
  inter_data<-rbind(inter_data,y_col)
  }
```

EDIT2:

By this loop I want to grab of y values from the following dataframe:

```
$gene949
$gene949$x
 [1] 1.000000 1.061224 1.122449 1.183673 1.244898 1.306122 1.367347 1.428571 1.489796 1.551020 1.612245 1.673469 1.734694 1.795918 1.857143 1.918367 1.979592 2.040816
[19] 2.102041 2.163265 2.224490 2.285714 2.346939 2.408163 2.469388 2.530612 2.591837 2.653061 2.714286 2.775510 2.836735 2.897959 2.959184 3.020408 3.081633 3.142857
[37] 3.204082 3.265306 3.326531 3.387755 3.448980 3.510204 3.571429 3.632653 3.693878 3.755102 3.816327 3.877551 3.938776 4.000000

$gene949$y
 [1] 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000
[15] 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000
[29] 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.02984865 0.11939459 0.20894053 0.29848647 0.38803241 0.47757835 0.56712429 0.65667023 0.74621616
[43] 0.83576210 0.92530804 1.01485398 1.10439992 1.19394586 1.28349180 1.37303774 1.46258368


$gene950
$gene950$x
 [1] 1.000000 1.061224 1.122449 1.183673 1.244898 1.306122 1.367347 1.428571 1.489796 1.551020 1.612245 1.673469 1.734694 1.795918 1.857143 1.918367 1.979592 2.040816
[19] 2.102041 2.163265 2.224490 2.285714 2.346939 2.408163 2.469388 2.530612 2.591837 2.653061 2.714286 2.775510 2.836735 2.897959 2.959184 3.020408 3.081633 3.142857
[37] 3.204082 3.265306 3.326531 3.387755 3.448980 3.510204 3.571429 3.632653 3.693878 3.755102 3.816327 3.877551 3.938776 4.000000

$gene950$y
 [1]  0.00000000 -0.15429366 -0.30858732 -0.46288099 -0.61717465 -0.77146831 -0.92576197 -1.08005564 -1.23434930 -1.38864296 -1.54293662 -1.69723029 -1.85152395
[14] -2.00581761 -2.16011127 -2.31440493 -2.46869860 -2.34260266 -2.07631192 -1.81002118 -1.54373044 -1.27743971 -1.01114897 -0.74485823 -0.47856749 -0.21227675
[27]  0.05401399  0.32030472  0.58659546  0.85288620  1.11917694  1.38546768  1.65175842  1.83847450  1.86604127  1.89360805  1.92117482  1.94874159  1.97630836
[40]  2.00387514  2.03144191  2.05900868  2.08657546  2.11414223  2.14170900  2.16927578  2.19684255  2.22440932  2.25197610  2.27954287
```

As it was suggested, there are for sure much better ways to achieve it than I do...

Comment: @akrun yes its within a for loop, but `paste` didn't help...

Comment: but I need doublequotes surrounding `gene`

Comment: Okay, I don't know for what purpose all of these are in strings

Comment: Agree with @akrun. Why are you pasting together R commands as strings? This looks like you want to achieve something that should be done in a completely different way.

Comment: I guess you are rights! there is a dataframe, which consists of lists, and each list has x and y lists. So I need to grab all y values from the dataframe.

Comment: Try `lapply(lst, function(x) x[names(x)=='y'])`

Comment: So, lapply(DF, "[[", "y")?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the edit in the OP's post, if we need to grab the 'y' elements in the `list` of `vector`s, then, loop through the `list`, get the `names` get a logical index by checking with 'y' and subset the elements

```
lapply(lst, function(x) x[names(x)=='y'])
```

Or use `[`

```
lapply(lst, `[`, 'y')
```

We can remove the nested part with `[[`

```
lapply(lst, `[[`, 'y')
```

#### data

```
lst <- list(gene949 = list(x = 1:5, y = 6:10), gene950 = list(x = 11:20, y = 21:30))
```

Comment: Sorry, and how can I rbind all these lists to a new dataframe by apply?

Comment: @Hrant  If the list elements are of the same length, then do `do.call(rbind, lapply(lst, '[[','y'))`  In the current example it won't work as I have different lengths.  If they are of different lengths, pad with NA and then `rbind` it. i.e. `lst1 <- lapply(lst, '[[', 'y'); do.call(rbind, lapply(lst1, 'length<-', max(lengths(lst1))))`

Comment: Thank you very much! R is so powerful if you know it:)

Answer (score 0):

The backslash isn't really there. It just shows that the following character (in this case, the quotation mark) is special. When you `print(...)` things to the console, it shows the data in a way useful to the programmer. In this case, the string is shown the way it would be written in code.

Look at the colors below to see how R would interpret the unescaped code:

```
"interpol_df[["gene1565"]][["y"]]"
```

Now here it is with the escapes:

```
"interpol_df[[\"gene1565\"]][[\"y\"]]"
```

The language definition lists other escape characters in [10.3.1: Constants](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Literal-constants).

Comment: Thanks for explaining. But when writing to a variable it becomes real:)